# How can I give background color to child div?

Tags: html, css

In my HTML page there is left panel and right panel.
In right panel there is a form contained in a div(wrapper).
And wrapper is contained in another div. Wrapper div has background yellow. 
But I want to make background yellow to whole right panel. Using CSS. 
I tried with min-height:100% and overflow:auto. But it not works.

Comment: Please post a snippet of jsfiddle of your code

Comment: Where are the codes?

Comment: Please add your html/css to your question, preferable a stack snippet as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#parent p").css({"background-color": "red"});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
<p>This is a child.</p>
</div>

<button>Set BG</button>
```